# Removing automatic PHP page heading* (not title)

Tags: php, wordpress, header

So I'm working on my blog page which uses a different page template, PHP isn't exactly my forte, and I feel like it should be a simple solution to remove the page header, but its all a bit out of my reach. [This is my site](http://www.overlandparkphotographer.com/contact-page/), and my code looks like this:

---

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Blog
*/
get_header(); 
get_template_part( "closer" ); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="primary" <?php bavotasan_primary_attr(); ?>>
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;

                bavotasan_pagination();
            else :
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<title>` resides in `header.php` of your theme in wordpress, and this page is i guess `index.php`

Comment: You want to remove 'Portrait Photographer in Overland Park & Kansas City Blog'??

Comment: Yea, i'm wanting to remove the top one.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this way,

Appearance > Editor > content-page.php (on the right side bar)>

Find: this  statement

the_title();

and simply comment it out.

//the_title();

or do the above change in content.php file

Comment: this looks like a good solution, only that i don't seem to have content-page.php ... I have content.php as well as content-____:
footer
gallerery
header
image
link
none
quote
status
video

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, and used `display: none` in my CSS. Probably not the best way to go, but it works.